# How to use DialogFlow without node-js or any other framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, dialogflow-es

I want to use Dialogflow to make a chatbot but I don't want to use Node-JS or any other framework to call the responses.

I want to access it just like a simple API, like we can use firebase by just adding some scripts.

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.3/firebase-app.js"></script>`

How to do so for Dialogflow.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? What do you mean by adding some script, what you want to achieve? Your chatbot is working and now you want to configure it differently? How did you create chatbot?

Comment: Actually I have to use this chat bot in a chrome extension and chrome extension don't works on node.js it only have a simple app.js like files which contains all the javascript code.
so in this case what should I do to use the dialogflow.

Comment: In short, you want to create chatbot (normal, not as chrome extension) using DialogFlow but you don't want to use any frameworks to call the responses. Do you have any agents, intents, etc? In [Dialogflow docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/intents-responses) you have info that `Intents have a built-in response handler that can return responses after the intent is matched. ` What you have now? Or you are looking for something like [Dialogflow API interactions](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/api-overview)

Comment: Yeah, I know what dialogflow is and have fair knowledge about agents, intents and fulfillment. I also know how to use it with node js or Python.What I want to know that is there any way to GET responses from my agent without use of any framework packages(i.e. - without npm or pip)